Holesky Testnet Can't add Peer?
I built 3 nodes on 3 different servers using geth and holesky testnet.
After that, for interworking with each other, after finding the enode value with "admin.nodeInfo.enode", I try to connect the nodes through the "admin.addPeer()" command, but when I input it, "true" is output, but when I check with "admin.peers" on other nodes, it cannot be confirmed.
The same Genesis block was used, and the network id was the same and all environments were the same.
All ports, firewalls, ip, etc. between each other are open.
If I use holesky testnet, can only the nodes that have already been determined be connected as peers in dns list, and can't the nodes that I built customly be connected?
No particular logs are output related, and admin.TrustedPeer() is also not working. What's the problem?
Plz help me 
